# Image not getting displayed in View

Tags: iphone

I am creating a simple app for iphone...I am just learning iphone programming..
I have just added image view and added a image to it...

When i run and build it...i am not able to see the image..

Am i missing something?

Comment: How/where are you setting the image to the image view?  You need to provide more information or sample code.

Comment: You need to add your image view to the visible window.  Either you add it directly or you add it as a subview of a view that is a subview of the window, etc...